# How can I insert records in bulk in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have to copy more than 100k records in the same table and after every row insert in first table, second table will be updated with first table insert ID (Primary key).
I tried to do bulk insert but then I would not get all the inserted ids which will be inserted in second table.
I am using MySQL 5.5. When I run the following code, I get following random errors:

1. Lost connection to MySQL server during query.
2. The transaction associated with the current connection has completed
   but has not been disposed. The transaction must be disposed before
   the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.
3. Net packets out of order: received[x], expected[y].

How can I insert these records optimally?

> `CODE;`

```
foreach (var item in transactions)
{
    int transactionId;
    using (MySqlCommand cm = DM.ConnectionManager.Conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        var commandText = @"INSERT INTO FirstTable SET 
                        column1=@column1;";
        cm.CommandText = commandText;
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column1", item.column1);

        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        transactionId = (int)cm.InsertId;
    }

    foreach (var item in item.TransactionDetails)
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cm = DM.ConnectionManager.Conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            var commandText = @"INSERT INTO SecondTable SET 
                        column1=@column1,
                        column2=@column2;";
            cm.CommandText = commandText;
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column1", item.column1);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column2", item.column2);

            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dang, right up my alley. Only problem, you haven't accepted any answers from yesteryear. So why bother

Comment: does MySql support bulk inserting data via XML.. if you have a datatable convert the datatable to XML and create a stored procedure that will take the XML as input and create sql stored proc code to handle the xml I do this all the time with SQL Server not sure if the same works in MySql do a good search on `C# Stackoverflow Bulk Insert XML into MySql Database`

Comment: @MethodMan: Yes, MySql does support bulk insert but i need to update the other table after every row update in first table, so can not use bulk. And there are lot other operations going on with the above code, which are in TrasactionScope. But still i will try your suggested method.

Comment: this can still be done if you were to store the xml in a temp table and create extra SQL within the first stored procedure to update using a `CASE WHEN` statement..but I'd need to know more information in regards to what you are truly trying to update.

Comment: @MethodMan: If you see the above code there are two for loop, outer loop have approx. 100k records and for every record(TransactionData) there are maximum 2 records(TransactionDetailsData). And after insertion in First Table I get the TransactionId (InsertId) which needs to be updated in Second Table.

Comment: have you thought about doing a majority of the work on the Server side..? I am sure there is always a more efficient way to do things whether inside code behind or Server Side in regards to Stored Procedures

Comment: Yeah, I WAS going to answer this, but then @Drew pointed out that there's no point. Shame.

Comment: I was just being a jerk. Nevermind me. I have a block of code I can share if pressed. But the details of this question need a little more info .. @AlexanderMP . And as MethodMan said, this needs to be done serverside. It would be screaming fast.

Comment: @Drew: with the similar above piece of code, there are other queries get executed with different MySQL connection. But all the option must be in c# TransactionScope with all its default option. And in my case outer loop have more than 100k TransactionDetails items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest method to import to MySQL is INFILE, so I would suggest making a CSV file and then running the following as a SQL statement.
Please note I've not got a full C# setup and tested this... but it is how I backup / restore MySQL when I want it done fast... so I'm assuming the following can be run when set to "commandText" and run after the CSV file is created and written to disk.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'import.csv' INTO TABLE MyTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (Col1,Col2,Col3);
```

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html "The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed..."

Comment: i have few doubts, 1. do I need to increase the timeout time of the MySQL connection or my c# transaction scope connection? 2. there are lot other query are executing in same c# transaction scope, Is t possible to read and insert in the same c# transaction scope?

Comment: Hi, I've seen that you dont' accept answers so with respect I'll leave my answer "as is" and repeat that it is my honest best recommendation for most efficient import into MySQL.  Be Well :)

Comment: sorry, @Barry i am newbie to these processes.

Comment: No worries, it will encourage more people to answer if they see you are accepting (at least some) answers.

Comment: in terms of your questions, I'm not sure about both... the timeout would depend on the size and duration it takes to import... the ability to read and write within the same transaction would be expected... this is just a MySQL command and MySQL commands are designed to be wrapped in transactions... but I've done neither of the above... I use this from PHP not C#... I just know that this is... by far... the fasted import to MySQL so I would advise to find a way to work with it

Comment: @Berry, thanks, it worked really well, now i am able to insert more than 100k records in just 1.5 to 2 seconds which was taking more than 40-45 seconds.

Comment: i did searching to find a way to load file from memory stream instead of text or csv files but no luck. does anyone know how to do in C#?